# Extending Map<>, or specifically HashMap<> to check entries before storing them

Tags: java

I need a Map<> implementation that allows me to check values before they are stored in Map. The Map<> interface itself defines a lot of ways (methods) to put values in Map<>. 
In HashMap<> implementation all those 'ways' go through a single method putVal(...) and that's the perfect place to put my checking code. However, the method is declared as 'final', so I can't subclass from HashMap and override it.

I'm mostly coding in C# and this problem is solved there in 3 mins. I'm actually very shocked right now, that I couldn't find a way to do this in Java.

How is it done? Do I really have to write my own full implementation of Map<>, or copy-paste HashMap<> source code and remove final before putVal?

Comment: why can't you check the data before actually putting them ito the map? Yo you really have different places which could try to add invalid data?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I'm not putting the data 'myself', I'm providing Map<> collection I have no idea how clients going to use it.

Comment: then IMHO you do something wrong: The map is your what ever object internal data store. This should not be changed from outside. So instead of returning the actual Map to your clients you should rather return an _unmodifiable_ version (`Collections.unmodifiableMap()`) of it and provide a method for your clients where they can provide data to be stored in your Map.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, Clients can and should modify it, my Map is like usual Map but it has some constraints when putting data.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use decorator pattern instead of extending the `HashMap`:

```
public class CheckingMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> delegate;

    public CheckingMap(Map<K, V> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public boolean put(K key, V value) {
        // do the check
        return delegate.put(key, value);
    }

    // etc
}
```

If implementing all the methods seems like a lot of code, you could use [Dynamic proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) that allows you to intercept all calls through one handler - but IMO that's needlessly complicated in this case.

Comment: This way I will still have to implement 50% of work myself. Map<> have a tons of ways it can be modified. All those methods, Put, PutAll, Replace,. entrySet(), etc etc

Comment: And I'm not sure but I think entrySet() returns modifiable inner map collection. So my Map still could be modified bypassing my checks, if I dont reimplement this

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a custom class e.g.

```
public class MySpecialHashMap{

private Map<> myActualMap;

public MySpecialHashMap() {
    myActualMap = new HashMap<>();
}

public void putItem(Object key, Object value) {
    // do your checks and add it to your map or not..
    }
}
```

Besides that you could use generics to define the type.

Comment: Can't change inheritance to composition in this case, the framework I'm using demands Map implementing object.

Answer (score 0):

Although I like Jiri's Decorator pattern idea, if you want support for an implementation, I'm not really sure what java classes you are using but the following works just fine for me.

```
class DerivedMap<V extends Object> extends HashMap {

    @Override
    public V put(Object key, Object value) {
        // Do yada yada
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
}
```